# How to let the chatMessageCell appear in DialogVC programmatically (Not StoryBoard)

Tags: sinch

I have gotten the program to send messages as Parse proves that. However i am not using storyboard & do not know display the textMessages in the Dialog view. How can i achieve displaying the textMessage in the dialog view with the same Cell you produced in Storyboard?

I am referring about the iOS tutorial for Parse-Sinch Chat messaging Application called MiniChat.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you create your view controller with a xib file, copy the code from the chat view and you should be fine. The story board only makes it easier to do navigation.